# Rails 3.1 routing--collection not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I recently upgraded to Rails 3.1 (from 3.0), and for some reason one of my routes no longer works. I have a form that posts a csv file, and is processed by an items controller. The route looks like:

```
  resources :items do 
    member do
      post 'receive'
      post 'show'
    end

    collection do
      post 'csv_import'
      get 'transactions'
      get 'template'
    end
  end
```

And here's what I see in the logs--it looks like it's posting the correct action.

```
Started POST "/items/csv_import" for 127.0.0.1 at Tue May 08 11:09:52 -0400 2012
  Processing by ItemsController#show as HTML
```

But it's being processed by the show action:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ItemsController#show

Couldn't find Item with id=csv_import
```

I can't for the life of me see what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: What does `rake routes` have to say?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `post 'show'` line is interfering with this, because when you post to `/items/csv_import`, rails thinks you mean `items/csv_import/show`, with `csv_import` being the id of the item you want to import. If you run `rake routes`, you'll see a part like this:

```
            item POST   /items/:id(.:format)        items#show
csv_import_items POST   /items/csv_import(.:format) items#csv_import
```

That first item is matching your post to `/items/csv_import` and it never even hits the second one.

You can move the `member do ... end` block to be after your `collection do ... end` block and it should work fine.

However, I would just recommend getting rid of `post 'show'` and renaming that method to something better, as it goes against the standard rails/rest conventions anyway.

Comment: Good eye! Another dev on project added that in, and I was looking right at it without seeing it. Thanks! Worked like a charm.